# How can I tell JAXB to generate classes in separate packages when two separate schemas have the same namespace?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, namespaces, jaxb

I suspect that there's no good answer to this, but hopefully I'm missing something. Let's say I have two separate XML schemas both with the same namespace, defining some duplicate complexTypes, and I want to generate Java classes for them with JAXB. As a very simplified example:

**schema1.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="namespace1" xmlns="namespace1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and

**schema2.xsd:** (identical to the above)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="namespace1" xmlns="namespace1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

When I try to generate these with JAXB (Ant XJC task via gradle), I get the following, entirely reasonable error:

```
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] 'foo' is already defined
[ant:xjc]   line 3 of file:/C:/dev/test/src/main/resources/schema2.xsd
[ant:xjc]
[ant:xjc] [ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
[ant:xjc]   line 3 of file:/C:/dev/test/src/main/resources/schema1.xsd
```

As per the [JAXB docs](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Customizing_Java_packages.html), I tried specifying the package in an external customisation file like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema1.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="package1"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema2.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="package2"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

but that doesn't work - I then realised that the same docs linked above say:

> Note that this customization is per namespace. That is, even if your schema is split into multiple schema documents, you cannot put them into different packages if they are all in the same namespace.

So, I'm guessing that's never going to work.

Is there any sensible approach to this? I suspect the correct answer is that the schemas should be in different namespaces, as that would resolve the issue, and probably make more logical sense, but I don't have any control over the schemas - they are provided by a 3rd party. I've asked if it's possible to change them, but I suspect the answer is no.

The only other option I can see is to generate the Java classes twice, first for schema1.xsd, and then separately for schema2.xsd, each time with their own customisation file specifying a different package, but that feels like a very clumsy solution. Is there any more sensible option that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Packages are generated based on namespaces. Same namespace - same package.

You have to do several executions in this case. Also mind to use different output generation directories (like `target/generated-sources/xjc1`, `target/generated-sources/xjc2`) otherwise "compile only if anything was changed" won't work correctly.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I wanted, but thanks for confirming my suspicions! Excellent tip on the different output directories too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

lexicore is right, you have to use several executions if you want to generate classes to different Java packages from the same XML namespace.

It may be so that you use the same XML types in both `schema1.xsd` and `schema2.xsd`, for example by including some `common.xsd` into both `schema1.xsd` and `schema2.xsd`. If you just run two executions, you will have those common types duplicated in `package1` and `package2`.

You can avoid such a duplication using the following method.

The method has been tested with `maven-jaxb-plugin` version `3.1.0`.

You have to make 4 XJB files:

- `common.xjb` and `common-classes.xjb` for the common types
- `schema1.xjb` for the types specific to `schema1.xsd`
- `schema2.xjb` for the types specific to `schema2.xsd`

`common.xjb` will put the common types into the `common` Java package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://namespace1">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="common"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`common-classes.xjb` will instruct `schema1` and `schema2` to reuse the common types from the `common` Java package:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://namespace1">
    <bindings scd="~tns:CommonType1">
      <class ref="common.CommonType1"/>
    </bindings>
    <bindings scd="~tns:CommonType2">
      <class ref="common.CommonType2"/>
    </bindings>
    <!-- ... -->
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Note that `maven-jaxb-plugin` can generate most of the `common-classes.xjb` file for you, from execution on the `common.xsd`. Check out the `target/classes/META-INF/JAXB` directory after the execution.

`schema1.xjb` will put the `schema1.xsd` specific types into `package1`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://namespace1">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="package1"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`schema2.xjb` will put the `schema2.xsd` specific types into `package2`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="https://namespace1">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="package2"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Finally, you have to define 3 `maven-jaxb-plugin` executions in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>

        <!-- Common configuration for all executions -->
        <configuration>
          <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc-common</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>common.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>common.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>xjc-schema1</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>schema1.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>common-classes.xjb</xjbSource>
                <xjbSource>schema1.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>xjc-schema2</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>schema2.xsd</source>
              </sources>
              <xjbSources>
                <xjbSource>common-classes.xjb</xjbSource>
                <xjbSource>schema2.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```